# Rails - Check if any Object in an Array is an ActiveRecord instance or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an Array of Objects how to check if any one of them is ActiveRecord or not ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can check with:

```
array.any? { |obj| obj.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Base) }
```

Answer (score 15):

You can check

```
object.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Base)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `obj` is the object, one way is to check using `===` operator of `Object` class.

```
array.any? { |obj| ActiveRecord::Base === obj }
```